# Webapps Stack Exchange swag for top users

Tags: discussion, swag

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 of …

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Webapps Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Webapps Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: webapps.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: webapps.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: woot, thank you!

Comment: rad! thanks very much

Comment: You guys are most excellent! Gracias!

Comment: Hey Jeff... Where should I contact regarding this package if I didn't receive anything yet and I'm leaving for vacations for 3 weeks? :D

Comment: @lipis I don't think this package has gone out yet, and might not for another 3 weeks. The guidance is 6-8 weeks. So hang in there.

Comment: @Jeff that's fine.. I just don't want to receive it while I'm not here..!! Thanks.. :)

Comment: *cough* 8 weeks.

Answer (score 6):

Can you get someone in the office to measure out the shirt sizes and post up the relations in centimetres/inches for the various sizes?

Especially the chest area since a lot of the time that's where the money is for knowing if you'll be breathing, flapping or constricting.

So it appears we have this:

```
                    SM   M     L     XL    2XL   3XL 
Body Width          18   20    22    24    26    28 
Body Length         28   29    31    32    32½   33
Sleeve Length (top) 7½   7¾    8     8½    9     9½
Sleeve Length (CBN) 16   16¾   17½   18½   19½   20½
Across Shoulder     17   18    19    20    21    22
```

Comment: see http://i.stack.imgur.com/fwqnJ.png and http://www.hanesprintables.com/catalog/CatalogProduct.aspx?ProductID=4980 (click the "Product Specs" sidebar)