# Has anyone received their swag package?

Tags: support, swag, first-anniversary

I got an email from the team for [WebApps swag](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/823/webapps-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) on June 15, 2011. I really appreciate that; thanks. Has anyone received their package yet? It's been more than 2 months and I just wanted to check if they were dispatched.

Comment: Nothing here. I'm trying to remember what the last status report was (apart from the usual "6-8 weeks").

Comment: Nothing here in Canada either. We will just have to wait 6-8 weeks for confirmation (:

Comment: Nada from India.

Comment: AFAIK it is in progress. Checking...

Comment: @Jeff - how's the progress?

Comment: should go out soon @chris

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The swag, it has made its appearance:

[image: swagamuffin]

That's got to be the funkiest Sharpie seen for a while.

Thanks for the swag, SE.

Comment: Just when I'm going to move away from the location that I had given for the swag to be shipped to...

Comment: Yes indeed - mine arrived today (13th Sept). With a little card saying "wash inside out". Hopefully it won't fade as much as the Gaming T did.

Comment: Got mine today as well (13th Sept). Mailman crumpled the package into the tiny mailbox, lucky none of the pens broke.

Comment: Got mine too today (September 13th) and I'm in Montreal, Canada.

Comment: Got middle of last week.

Answer (score 3):

I just got the swag (September 15th). Thanks @Jeff & the team.

Answer (score 3):

Swag arrived today, 3rd of October! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I got my Swag today - 19th September - yay! Send date was 9th July... didn't know the post took so long from US to NZ!