# Celebrating our Birthday

Tags: discussion, contest, first-anniversary

### Happy Birthday!!!

It's been suggested we have a competition to celebrate our first birthday.

In a similar format to [Super User](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/), the contest would most likely last two weeks and there will be prizes for newcomers and *the old guys as well*.

So we have decided to match the categories Super User created as we believe them to be reasonable. The following is a starting draft so the final number/qualification per category may change.

1. **The Upcoming Editor:**  The top three users gaining the most reputation from suggested edits. Users with more than 3 rejected edits are disqualified.
   Three Level 3 prizes awarded.
2. **The Upcoming Tag Wikifier:** The top three users gaining the most reputation from suggested tag wiki edits.
   Three Level 3 prizes awarded.
3. **The Top Gun Rookies:** The top three, in order of the best performance for a new user.
   One Level 1, 2, and 3 prize awarded
4. **The Editors:** The top three most useful editors as judged by the judges.  Candidates are selected from the top 10 editors for the time period of the contest. They must have at least 10 non-trivial edits.
   One Level 1, 2, and 3 prize awarded.
5. **The Most Valued Users:** (This will need some thinking) but the breakdown will be:

   - Six Level 3 prizes
   - Four Level 2 prizes
   - Two Level 1 prizes
   - One Grand Prize

In terms of quantification we will be asking the folks over at Super User for some advice. The prizes will be taken care of so hopefully there will not be problems in terms of prizes outside of the U.S. This post serves mainly to see the community's view and what suggestions/improvements *you* have for the contest.

**Moderators on WebApps (and any other judges) are exempt from the prize draw**

### Prizes??

<sub>hopefully this is okay with SE Inc</sub>

**Level 3 Prize:** An official [WebApps T-Shirt](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/912/has-anyone-received-their-swag-package/932#932)

**Level 2 Prize:** $25 worth of SE swag from the official [SE Store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/)

**Level 1 Prize:** $100 worth of web app subscriptions or SE swag (Can be a combination from both)

**The Grand Prize:** $200 worth of web app subscriptions or SE swag (Can be a combination from both)

(Stay tuned...)

Thanks for all the work everyone has put in over the past year. We survived Area51, Beta and are still here kicking. Here is to a next year of awesome contributions.

Comment: Do you have an idea on the prizes?

Comment: @Eig I'm thinking the SE swag for smaller prizes. The larger ones I  had the idea of app subscriptions (e.g. a Pro 50 GB Dropbox for a year or [rdio](http://www.rdio.com/) year subscription). It's hard to match an equivalent to software/hardware that is a permanent (not a subscription) prize.

Comment: Probably worth noting that Moderators are exempt from the prize draw (assuming we are adopting the same rules as SU)

Comment: A Chromebook would make sense since it's supposed to be built for cloud/web apps. But that winning category might have to be something mighty

Comment: I like the idea of a Chromebook...but $200 of swag sounds good too. :P

Comment: @studiohack The mods are discussing it right now the above will have some changes. It will be a mix between the current edit, previous edits and Eight answer.

Comment: @phwd Cheers! I look forward to the contest! :)

Comment: @Barry App subscriptions are good, except that they aren't available everywhere - for example: Netflix, Pandora aren't available in most Asian countries. (So much for Global Internet). Just a thought.

Answer (score 8):

Since Web Apps is a tighter, smaller, band of users with a different set of actors in play, we could pare down some of those categories.

You'd have games down in the following fields:

- **Top Gun Editor** - Tag wiki and post editors lumped into the one since otherwise you'll see a lot of unnecessary flooding when tag wikis might be crying alone in a corner.
- **Most flexible** - Since the array of web apps is wide, something that gives a nod to the fact that it isn't all Google+ or Facebook would be nice. Being able to answer questions about all sorts of web apps would be like a step toward Generalist.
- **The Jan Itor** - Combined flags, edits, close votes and helpful comments that help steer and scope the site.
- **MVP** - The one that tops the crop across all. Judged by fellow users.

Getting an upvote is hard on a normal day. Pushing a run for reputation might not quite have the legs.