# Web Applications Anniversary Contest

Tags: discussion, contest, first-anniversary

### The Contest is now closed

#### Please check back later for updates here or on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7) for the winners

---

If you were following from [Celebrating our Birthday](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/969/celebrating-our-birthday), we would like to have a contest so here it is!!!

**Proposed start date November 4<sup>th</sup> 16:00 EST for two weeks until November 18<sup>th</sup> 16:00 EST**
Mark your Google Calendars!

### Judges

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/21/chrisf
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/5095/barry
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/40/phwd

### Rules

- You must have a registered Web Applications account in good standing, with a valid email address, to be eligible.
- Contest open to every man, woman, and child (over 13, as per our TOS) on planet Earth, except those men, women, or children living in places where contests like this are somehow illegal — or the relevant contest laws in your jurisdiction are so obnoxious that awarding the prize becomes impractical.
- Web Application Moderators, and Judges of any kind are not eligible to win, because they will be judging parts of the contest. This includes SE Employees and Chaos Team.
- You cannot win more than one prize, the runner up will receive the unclaimed prize.
- If you live in an area of the world where it is logistically impossible for us to get your prize to you — like, say, because your nearest computer hardware store is 3000 nautical miles away — we’ll do our best to work with you and make it happen.
- **We will try to be as fair as possible, but all of our judgments are final and binding.**

### Contest Level

The contest will not have any runner-ups but instead winners based on when they have contributed. So it will be a mixture of thank you awards and prizes. There will be three levels:

**All-time: [$100 worth of a web application subscription]**
Users in this level are selected based on all their contributions to the site regardless of time period. This will ensure that older users get recognition for outstanding work done in the past.

**Open: [$35 worth of merchandise in the [SE store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show)]**
Users in this level are selected based on their activity in the two week time period of the competition.

**New Users: [[Web Applications T-Shirt]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/823/webapps-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users)**
Users who have registered within the *last two months* (September - October)

**Grand Prize**
A [Chromebook](http://www.google.com/chromebook/)

### Categories

**Top Gun Editor (All-time, Open, New)**
This will be the user with the top useful edits across posts. This user will be chosen from the top editors of that contest level.

**Tag Wiki Editor (All-time, Open, New)**
This will be the user with the top useful edits across posts.

**Most Flexible User (All-time, Open, New)**
Similar to the [Generalist badge](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/15/generalist), this will be a user who provides the top total score in 20 of the top 40 tags (over the two week period)

**The Janitor (All-time, Open, New)**
This user will have the most combined flags, edits and helpful comments that help steer and scope the site.

**The Voter (All-time, New)**
This user *will have voted the most*. No new votes after October 31st are tallied here but we appreciate you voting. You never know what will happen later on ;)

**The Most Valued User (Grand Prize)**
He/she will be the combination of the previous five categories, such that they rank in *at least* the top five users out of three of these categories. These are the requirements. Users can *nominate* themselves or others but please remember that moderators will be the final judges of this prize.

See [Nominations open for the Most Valued Web Applications User](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/991/nominations-open-for-the-most-valued-web-applications-user) for more details.

Let's go! Again thanks for all the contributions you have made to this site!!!

[image: Challenge Accepted]

Comment: *challenge accepted.* start your engines!

Comment: The results are on their way. We are just trying to get some data put together before releasing it. We do not want to make any mistakes in the selection of users.