# Nominations open for the Most Valued Web Applications User

Tags: discussion, contest, first-anniversary

### Nominations are now closed

#### Please check back later for updates here or on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7) for the winner

---

In celebration of [Web Applications' 1st Anniversary](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/979/web-applications-anniversary-contest), we are holding a contest to reward the most active, helpful, and involved members of our community. The grand prize will be awarded to one of **you**.

The award isn't just about reputation earned - it's about how much you've dedicated yourself to the community. Think of the users whose names you see helping the site out every day: editing, flagging, cleaning up, closing bad questions, and of course providing lots of great answers. Statistics are great, but we want *you*, the users of this site, to choose who you think has had the greatest positive impact on this site.

There are a few rules, to ensure that users have met certain minimum criteria for what the judges think a valued user ought to be. **Users must meet these criteria *by the end of the competition***. You are welcome to nominate a user who does not have all of these things yet, as long as you believe they can in two weeks' time.

- At least **900 rep earned this year**. Use [this link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year) to double check.
- At least **200 flag weight**
- Earned the following **badges** (hover for requirements):

  [citizen patrol](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol),
  [suffrage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/193/suffrage),
  [tag editor](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/187/tag-editor),
  [quorum](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/badges/198/quorum)

Currently **active on the site** (must visit and participate at some point during the contest)

**He/she will be decided at the end of the contest, by the judges on the combination of the five categories, such that they rank in at least the top five users out of three of these categories.**

- Top Gun Editor
- Tag Wiki Editor
- Most Flexible User
- The Janitor
- The Voter

See [Web Applications Anniversary Contest](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/979/web-applications-anniversary-contest) post for details on these categories.

Now we understand that you may not be able to view all of the exact statistics, but don't worry — we'll be monitoring each candidate to make sure they meet the criteria and are upstanding internet citizens. This portion of the contest is meant to bring attention to those dedicated users who keep this site running, and may not always get the credit they deserve. They truly are the most valuable users.

---

How nominations/ works

Any registered user may nominate any other user (except for contest judges/♦ mods/Chaos Team/SE employees), providing the candidate meets the above criteria, or likely will by the end of the competition.

Nominations should be entered as a single answer with the user's name, and a link to their profile. Include their Web Applications image flair so we can get an idea for what they've done. **All commentary, endorsements, etc. should go in the comments below the answer**. Use this template:

```
#[Username][7]

[![Username][8]][7]

[7]: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/WEBAPPS_ID
[8]: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/flair/WEBAPPS_ID.png
```

***for example...***

> ## [ChrisF](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/21)
>
> [image: ChrisF]

<sub>Note that judges/moderators have final say in the contest - any decisions regarding users deemed disqualified are final.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

## [Al Everett](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354)

[image: Al Everett]

Answer (score 6):

## [Eight Days of Malaise](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/410)

[image: Eight Days of Malaise]

Comment: I'd endorse this. I see more questions with EDoM's name in the "edited by" than not.

Answer (score 6):

## [Mehper C. Palavuzlar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88)

[image: Mehper C. Palavuzlar]

Comment: Another one whose name I see constantly in "edited by". +1!

Answer (score 4):

## [Alex](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/1512/alex)

[image: Alex]

Answer (score 4):

## [Sathya](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/310)

[image: Sathya]