# Web Applications Anniversary Contest - The Winners

Tags: discussion, contest

As you may be aware, Web Apps held a [contest to win some swag](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/979/web-applications-anniversary-contest) to celebrate our 1 year anniversary.

The contest officially ended at 16:00 EST on 18th November and your friendly Web Apps Moderators have been collating all the information so we can hand out some free swag!

We also had to make a decision as to who walks away with a brand spanking new [Google Chromebook](http://www.google.com/chromebook/) as our Most Valued User.

Before the winners are announced there is a slight change to the competition...

After reviewing the data, we took the decision to remove the **Open** level from the **Top Gun Editor** category as the required criteria was not filled.

Unfortunately, we weren't allowed to keep the spare swag for ourselves, so there are now two winners for the **Open** level in the **Janitor** category.  You lucky people!

So, [drumroll please](http://instantrimshot.com/classic/?sound=drumroll)...

## The Winners!

> ### Top Gun Editor
>
> **New User**
>
> [image: profile for Bobby Grace at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]
>
> **All-Time**
>
> [image: profile for Senseful at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]

> ### Tag Wiki Editor
>
> **New User**
>
> [image: profile for kopischke at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]
>
> **Open**
>
> [image: profile for Sathya at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]
>
> **All-Time**
>
> [image: profile for studiohack at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]

> ### Most Flexible User
>
> **New User**
>
> [image: profile for Dave at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]
>
> **Open:**
>
> [image: profile for neo at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]
>
> **All-Time:**
>
> [image: profile for Mehper C. Palavuzlar at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]

> ### The Janitor
>
> **New User**
>
> [image: profile for V413HAV at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]
>
> **Open:**
>
> [image: profile for Rich Armstrong at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]
>   
>   
>   
>   [image: profile for jonsca at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]
>
> **All-Time:**
>
> [image: profile for Alex at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]

> ### The Voter
>
> **New User**
>
> [image: profile for DQdlM at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]
>
> **All-Time:**
>
> [image: profile for Al Everett at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]

The Web Applications user who bags themselves a new Chromebook and the prestigious title of

### Web Apps Most Valued User

[image: profile for Eight Days of Malaise at Web Applications, Q&A for power users of web applications]

**Congratulations to all of our winners!**

All winners will be contacted via email by a member of the Stack Exchange team with instructions on how to claim your prize.

Comment: Congratulations to all the winners! :)

Comment: W00t! (and other expressions of wootiness)