# Web Applications Anniversary Contest Prizes

Tags: support, contest

Have any of the [*all-time* winners](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1050/1512) received their prizes - [$100 worth of a web application subscription](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/979/1512)?

A while back I received an email with a link to a Google Forms form, which I completed, but feedback since.

Comment: Sorry about that. We'll get back to you as soon as we can.

Comment: I emailed the staff last week, have not heard a response.

Comment: @phwd Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex,

Sorry for the delay on this - I handled getting most of the prizes out back in January, so missed that you'd updated the spreadsheet in February.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to purchase GMail storage as a gift; can you think of some other web app you could use that we can actually *buy?*

Comment: No problem. No, I don’t at the moment. I’ll think about it and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: kinda looking to get this off my plate - perhaps I could interest you in something from [the SE store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/show)?

Comment: Yeah, I guess we can fix it this way, no problem. How do we proceed?

Comment: Just let me know what you want, @Alex.

Comment: OK. So, one [SE hoodie](http://bit.ly/LU4HGg) (size M), one [SO hoodie](http://bit.ly/M8Uqok) (size M), one [Area 51 t-shirt](http://bit.ly/MdV9mo) (size M) and one white [SE t-shirt](http://bit.ly/N0eGt3) (size M).

Comment: Cool. Is your address still the same?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Out of curiosity, what is the usual delivery time? I’m asking because, if I remember correctly, the previous package was delivered after more than a month, if not more—is that normal or it was an exception?

Comment: To Italy? Yeah, it could easily take a while. International shipping tends to be a bit unpredictable that way.

Comment: Got it. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Man, USPS really takes its time.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to track the delivery status of the package? It’s been almost three months and I’m curious of its whereabouts.

Comment: I'll look into it, @Alex - wouldn't be the first time a package headed that way up and disappeared.

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine. Thanks, @Shog9.

Comment: Hey @Shog9, sorry to bother you again, but it’s been almost four months and still no sign of the package. Do you know anything about it? Should I still expect it to arrive (and if yes, when will it arrive?), or should we find another way to fix this?

Comment: I’m sorry if I’m annoying, but do you have any news about my package? It’s been more than four months now and nothing has arrived.

Comment: @Alex: we've re-sent it; tracking tells us it made it out of the US, but no telling what happened to it after that. If you don't get it this time, you might want to check if any of your local postal workers are wearing SE apparel...

Comment: OK, thanks! I’ll keep an eye on the postal workers.

Comment: @Alex Receive your package yet? I think there now is a way to purchase GMail storage as a gift, just in case you need to resort to your original request.

Comment: @FeralOink Yeah, I found out that. No, unfortunately nothing arrived yet. :(

Comment: Two more months passed and still no package in sight. And I was really looking forward for those hoodies. :(

Comment: @Alex I feel really badly for you. You have 12,000 rep on this site, and won the 2012 contest, yet it is now January 2013, but you haven't received anything yet. Romania is not as remote as McMurdo Station or Tahiti, so you should have received something by now. I was going to ask about it on MSO, but I don't want to embarrass you, like I am your mother complaining! Do you mind if I ask, or would you rather that I don't interfere?

Comment: I am Ellie. I don't have any children, but I see you waiting for your prize that you won by fair means, yet it never arrived. That makes me feel sad. I want to help make things right, so you don't get discouraged or feel slighted. Life isn't fair, but we can try to make it more fair, in the few small ways that are within are power to do so. That is my thinking.

Comment: *Still* nothing @Alex? This is getting ridiculous... Do you have a friend, perhaps, in a different location that we could try sending to? I hate to blame your local postal service, but twice lost is too much.

Comment: @Shog9 Zip, zero, zilch, nada. Probably the safer option would be to be sent with a service that allows tracking from departure to delivery (e.g. UPS, TNT), but I don’t know if the costs are worth the trouble. Otherwise, perhaps send it to a different location in Italy? Or in France?

Comment: @FeralOink It’s not Romania at the moment, actually, it’s Italy. You wouldn’t embarrass me, don’t worry, but I don’t think it’s worth the trouble—it’s just a series of unfortunate events. :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Alex: if that's workable for you, email me privately with an address in France and I'll get it sent there. Thanks!

Comment: @Shog9 Did you get my email today?

Comment: Yup - should be sent shortly, @Alex. This is gonna have to be the last try I'm afraid.

Comment: Let’s hope third time’s a charm! Thanks a lot, @Shog9!

Comment: Third time _was_ a charm! My friends just informed me that they received the package. Thanks a lot, @Shog9!

Comment: Good to hear, @Alex!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they did. I wasn't directly involved in the prize side, but I'll make sure that someone from SE sees this.

Comment: I didn’t and that’s why I asked. And I asked it now because, somehow (I don’t know why), I assumed it will take some time, just as it took with the [swag package](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/912/1512).

Comment: Also, thanks a lot!